# Did java.time.LocalDate and java.time.ZonedDateTime apply the factory pattern

Tags: design-patterns, java-8

In core Java 8's date and time library, i.e. those classes in the package `java.time`, I found a special common trait: there is no public constructor in each class of this package, and thus all classes can be instantiated only through some `static` methods such as `of`, `now` etc. In this sense, the classes inside `java.time` resembles the *factory design pattern*. However, these classes do differ from *factory design pattern* in that the essence of *factory design pattern* is to loose couple the code to instantiate various types of objects with a common method (usually `static`), and thus the type of the returned object instance is determined until runtime.

However, esp. in the class `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime`, the keyword **factory** was mentioned. One can find the keyword **factory** from:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html

So I would like to know did `java.time.LocalDate` and `java.time.ZonedDateTime` apply the *factory design pattern* at all? If not, what design pattern did they apply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that they wanted to apply the rule

> Consider static factory methods instead of constructors

from the book [**Effective Java** by *Joshua Bloch*](https://www.amazon.de/Effective-Java-2nd-Programming-Language/dp/0321356683).

The goal of that rule is that static methods can be more descriptive as constructors, because a method has a name.

For example:

```
ZonedDateTime.now();
```

is more descriptive than

```
new ZonedDateTime();
```

is, isn't it?

You might also want to read: [Joshua Bloch #Item 1: Consider static factory methods instead of constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38563189/974186)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This is what I would like to know. So it is *static factory method*. As the book - Effective Java - you mentioned told: a static factory method is not the same as the Factory Method pattern from Design Patterns [Gamma95, p. 107]. The static factory method described in this item has no direct equivalent in Design Patterns

Answer (score 2):

I see at least three reasons for this choice (and yes that is the factory pattern) :

This way it could in future return a specialized `LocalDate` for example, which could be extended only internally (since there are no user-availabe constructors). This way the specialized classes would not be exposed to the clients - only known internally. That seems like exactly your point about different types at runtime - *at the moment* they don't return any particular subtype, but they might in future.

It would potentially cache some instances for example - I don't think it does that at the moment, but that still remains an option.

Some of the methods have descriptive names: `ofYearDay`, `ofInstance`, etc.

Comment: thanks a lot for your opinion :) there is one point I feel doubt: the `LocalDate` is `final` class and *immutable*, so there seems not to be any *extension* in the future