# Fix grammtical or spelling errors?

Tags: java

I want to test this method in a junit and one more.

Comment: You typed `fahrenheit` instead of `Fahrenheit` in your `test()` method. Java is case sensitive.

Comment: where is your method?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to instantiate an object of class fahrenheit in your test class, then since you dont have a class named fahrenheit you are getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a new instance of `Temperature`, which should look like this: `Temperature temperature = new Temperature();`. You can use this to set the internal fahrenheit value of 30 `temperature.setFahrenheit(30);` and get the celcius value by `double celsius = temperature.toCelsius();`

Comment: I can't do temperature = new Temperature(30);. I can only do temperature = new Temperature();                                                                                                        
   @Test
 public void test() {
 Temperature temperature = new Temperature();
double Temperature = 30; 
 double celsius = temperature.toCelsius();
 }

}                                                            This is what I did now, but I feel like I'm doing it wrong

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: Anyway there are some things that could improve your solution. Passing an initial value via constructor or using static factory methods https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38561736/joshua-bloch-item-1-consider-static-factory-methods-instead-of-constructors . This would enable you to do something like `Temperature.fromFahrenheit(30)` or `Temperature.fromCelsius(50)`.

Comment: Additionally `toFahrenheit(double tempC)` and `toCelsius(double tempF)` could always be replaced by their parameterless implementations and vice versa. Would that reduce your feeling of doing something wrong?

Comment: I thought I could do this after,  Temperature expected = new Temperature(86);
But I'm getting an error now, the same as when I put 30 in parentheses

Comment: Did you add the constructor?
`public class Temperature {    private double fahrenheit = 0; /* Constructor*/ public Temperature(final double fahrenheit) {    this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;    }`. Sorry, multiline code looks messy.

Comment: Yes, now I can put the number inside the parentheses!

Comment: After I input double celsius = temp.toCelsius(); 
Since I'm using a Junit test, how would I make sure that the celsius value is equal to 86 degrees from 30 degrees Fahrenheit using a unit? This is all of my code so far.     
         public class Testing {

 @Test
 public void test() {
 Temperature temp = new Temperature(30); 
 double celsius = temp.toCelsius();
 Temperature expected = new Temperature(86);
 }

Comment: What about this?
 @Test
 public void test() {
 Temperature temp = new Temperature(30); 
 double Temperature = temp.toCelsius();
 Temperature expected = new Temperature(86);
 assertEquals(expected, temp);
 }

Comment: More something like this: `@Test public void test() { Temperature temp = new Temperature(30); double actual = temp.toCelsius(); double expected = 86.0; assertEquals(expected, actual); }`

Comment: This is what I have done.                                                                                      
package JunitAssignment;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Testing {

 @Test
 public void testcelsius() {
 Temperature temp = new Temperature(30); 
 double result = temp.toCelsius();
 double expected = 86;
 assertEquals(expected, result);
 }
 public void testfahrenheit() {
  Temperature temp1 = new Temperature(86); 
  double result1 = temp1.toCelsius();
  double expected1 = 30;
  assertEquals(expected1, result1);
 }
}

Comment: When I run it, it only says testcelsius. Should it also include test Fahrenheit or should I create a new class for testfahrenheit?

Comment: What I'm asking is I get a result of Runs1/1 Errors:0 and Failures:1 and Testcelsius=0.031 sec Should I get that? Actually, now I see the testfahrenheit, but I'm getting failures both times

Comment: Also for some reason, now for my Temperatureconverter.java , for   converter = new Temperature();
I get an error under new Temperature(); saying the constructor is undefined

Comment: Because you created a constructor, the default constructor is gone. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488716/java-default-constructor

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: I fixed it but still get a failurepackage JunitAssignment;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Testing {

 @Test
 public void testcelsius() {
 Temperature temp = new Temperature();
 temp.setCelsius(30.0);
 double result = temp.toFahrenheit();
 double expected = 86.0;
 assertEquals(expected, result);
 }